# Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named ServiceRequest

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, graphql, nestjs, serverless

package.json

```
{ 
"name": "danjorepair_api",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "",
"author": "",
"private": true,
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
  "build": "nest build",
  "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
  "start": "nest start",
  "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
  "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
  "start:prod": "node dist/main",
  "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
  "test": "jest",
  "test:watch": "jest --watch",
  "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
  "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
  "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
},
"dependencies": {
  "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.22",
  "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.0.22",
  "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
  "apollo-server-express": "^3.10.2",
  "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
  "aws-serverless-express": "^3.4.0",
  "graphql": "^16.6.0",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
  "moment": "^2.29.4",
  "pg": "^8.8.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
  "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
  "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
  "typeorm": "^0.3.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
  "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
  "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
  "@types/jest": "28.1.4",
  "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
  "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
  "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
  "eslint": "^8.0.1",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
  "jest": "28.1.2",
  "plugin": "^0.3.3",
  "prettier": "^2.3.2",
  "serverless-offline": "^12.0.3",
  "serverless-plugin-optimize": "^4.2.1-rc.1",
  "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.4",
  "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
  "supertest": "^6.1.3",
  "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
  "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
  "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
  "tsconfig-paths": "4.0.0",
  "typescript": "^4.3.5"
},
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "rootDir": "src",
  "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.(t|j)s"
  ],
  "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
}
```

serverless.yaml

```
service: nest-serverless-lambda-demo

plugins:
 - 'serverless-plugin-typescript'
 - serverless-plugin-optimize
 - serverless-offline

    
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    httpPort: 4000
    stageVariables:
      foo: "bar"
    allowCache: true


provider:
 name: aws
 runtime: nodejs12.x
 timeout: 100

functions:
 main: # The name of the lambda function
   # The module 'handler' is exported in the file 'src/lambda'
   handler: src/lambda.handler
   events:
     - http:  
        method: ANY
        path: graphql
```

Facing the above error with the relevant files. Trying to deploy a serverless application. The error is coming while the following command:

```
sls offline start
```

I saw a resolution to this using the following command but faced the error in the right part of the image:

```
npx serverless offline --allowCache
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your grapql models.
Probably define same name in different models.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963126/5589820

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked for the same. Is there any way to identify it? What file should I share to be able to help?